# Guidance for app to be installed at client's machines, storing config data and scheduling tasks

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, configuration, installation

I have a web app and want to transfer data from client's machines to us every day. Assume there is a common API on every client machine to extract data from. To make this work, I have to create:

1. An API to receive data from clients - using WCF, seems ok at this point
2. An application that's installed on client machines

The client app needs to store info from the user (eg username/password to access our API - encrypted with DPAPI). The app needs to run daily (probably with a random Sleep() command so our API isn't overloaded all at once). It also needs to be easy to install.

I've created a console app which talks with the client API and our own API. I've used Visual Studio's Settings.settings with a user scope to save the persistent settings - if parameters are provided then it stores these settings, if no parameters it uses the stored settings.

**How can I make this usable for the end user?** I'm thinking a separate installer/configuration program that installs the exe file (and its dependencies) and asks the user to enter the settings to be stored (which can also be read by the client app). It would have to set up the scheduled task and also offer the ability to change the configuration (the stored shared variables).

Hoping someone can help architect this solution?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your idea about an installer is correct since you will most likely have dependencies or prequisites to install.

However, rather than building the settings logic into the installer, I would recommend that you build a UI for this in your application so that the user can adjust it post-installation if needed.

For example, if the user changes their password, in your current design, the user will have to uninstall and reinstall the app. Also, if the scheduled time is incompatible with some other operations on their machine, then they will need to adjust the time without uninstalling and reinstalling.

You could build the UI and API interface into a single application: just change the behavior (runtime or configuration) with a command line switch (for example, only use a /runtime command line switch for the scheduled task).